# Custom directive in Akka Http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have some API Rest with `CRUD` operations.
Each entity is identified by using `UUID`.

For example for `Create` it is similar to this:

```scala
  private val createProduct = post {
    path("product" / Segment) { productUUID =>
        Try(UUID.fromString(productUUID)) match {
          case Failure(_) => // Bad request
          case Success(validUuid) =>
            entity(as[ProductData]) { productData =>
              onComplete(addProduct(validUuid, productData)) {
                case Success(_)  => complete(StatusCodes.OK)
                case Failure(ex) => // some code 
              }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Operations `Read`(`GET`), `Update`(`PUT`) and `Delete`(`DELETE`) are similar to POST:

- first step is get the uuid
- for `PUT` get the payload using `entity(as[ProductData])` (not needed for `GET` and `DELETE`)
- invoke some method that returns `Future[Something]`

What I would like to do is remove boilerplate like:

- getting the `UUID`, validating it, returning `Bad Request` if it's not valid
- create some directive/function for handling the future: if there's an exception just return `500 Internal Server Error`, but in case of `Success` continue for processing the value (I think using `provide` directive).

I found this example (https://fmsbeekmans.com/blog/akka-http-2-creating-custom-directives.html):

```scala
def simplifiedOnComplete[T](future: Future[T])(timeout: FiniteDuration): Directive1[T] = {
  Try(Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)) match {
    case Success(result) => provide(result)
    case Failure(error) => failWith(error)
  }
}
```

I said, ok, there's a try in this example! Maybe I can change it for working with `UUID` instead of `Future`:

```scala
  def getUUID[T]: Directive1[T] = {
    path(Segment) { maybeuuid =>
      Try(UUID.fromString(maybeuuid)) match {
        case Success(result) => provide(result) // compilation error here
        case Failure(error)  => failWith(error)
      }
    }
  }
```

The code does not compile with the error:
`Type mismatch. Required: Route, found: Directive1[UUID]`
I guess the problem is I've added `path` ...

How can I create a `Directive` to extract the valid `uuid` and return `Bad Request` if it's not valid?
And, is it possible to encapsulate in a custom directive the code that handles de future?

For example the routes defined at the top would be something like:

```scala
  private val createProduct = post {
     path ("product") {
        extractUUID { validUUID =>
           entity(as[ProductData]) { productData => 
              futureSuccess(addProduct(validUUID, productData)) { successValue =>
                 // code here, for example: complete(OK)
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there - Your code is :

```
  def getUUID[T]: Directive1[T] = {
    path(Segment) { maybeuuid =>
      Try(UUID.fromString(maybeuuid)) match {
        case Success(result) => provide(result) // compilation error here
        case Failure(error)  => failWith(error)
      }
    }
  }
```

1. You don't need generic `T` since you can only have a `UUID` back from `UUID.fromString`
2. `path(Segment)` gives you a `Directive`. So you want to use`flatMap` to get a `Directive` back (`provide` returns a Directive)

So it would be something like

```
  def getUUID: Directive1[UUID] = {
    path(Segment).flatMap { maybeuuid =>
      Try(UUID.fromString(maybeuuid)) match {
        case Success(result) => provide(result) 
        case Failure(error)  => failWith(error)
      }
    }
  }
```

> And, is it possible to encapsulate in a custom directive the code that
> handles de future?

Yes, it is the same as the above. `onComplete` returns a `Directive` so you will have to `flatMap`.

To return `BadRequest`, look up the rejection handlers in the akka-http doc.

Comment: I swear I tried yesterday removing the type parameter and it didn't worked (code did not compiled) ... obviously I was doing something wrong. Anyway thanks for the help, your code it's working !! I'm going to read the docs for rejection handlers.